# Why : "Strategy objects often make good flyweights"?

Tags: design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strategy and Flyweight patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061214/strategy-and-flyweight-patterns)

Why is the following true:

"Strategy objects often make good flyweights" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please link to the source. Some context is needed.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2061214/1583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061214/strategy-and-flyweight-patterns/2061284#2061284) SO answer:

> If I'm not mistaken, the point of saying that Strategy objects make good Flyweights is that they often encapsulate no state (since they represent algorithms rather than entities) and can be reused.